# achartengine cannot show all line labels

Tags: android, achartengine, fragment-tab-host

I have more than **10 lines** to show **in a line graph**.

I put the `GraphicalView` generated by `ChartFactory.getTimeChartView` into a `Fragment`.

 So, the `GraphicalView` is wrapped inside a `LinearLayout`, and the `LinearLayout` is wrapped inside a `ScrollView`.

And then, I tried to show the fragment in a `FragmentTabHost`.

The problem is there even I used a `ScrollView`, the scrolling seems to happen inside the graph.

[Picture 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F8_9FhSb0_WFk4VFpQT3BTWDg/edit?usp=sharing)
: At the bottom, some names of the lines are cut off.

When I try to scroll down, it looks like this: [Picture 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F8_9FhSb0_aHdvVGlNUUJEQU0/edit?usp=sharing)
. Only the inside of the graph is dragged, instead of the whole graph.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually fixed using:

```
mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
```